# 405 (Method Not Allowed) error while trying to upload with blueimp jquery upload widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp, http-status-code-405

I want to use basic version of blueimp jquery upload widget. But I m getting an error  like below:

POST "../(my url)"  405 (Method Not Allowed)

my code is like that:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="../uploads/" multiple>
```

And also basic one upload code is like that:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    }
});
```

What is the mistake. Should not be The data-url is like that? I want to put uploaded file to that shown url. Interesting thing is if I open the not allowed url at the new tab, it shows related url. no error about this issue.

Comment: already found the anwser?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this ?

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    method:'post',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    }
});
```